# How to read from a file in custom App component in next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, getstaticprops

I have a requirement to read a file in _app component and pass its content through a provider to make it available to the whole application.

The project is using `antd` for components and `emotions` for styling. Since `antd` uses `less` for styling, we wanted to declare global variables in a single `less` file then using `less-vars-to-js` convert and share it via `emotion's ThemeProvider` to make use of them in the whole application. Also want to share the antd dark and light themes with emotion for dynamic theme switch.

In next.js we can read files in `getStaticProps`, but that is not available to be used in the `_app` component and `getInitialProps` doesn't seem to work for this either.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What specific issues are you having?

Comment: Updated question with some details.